# How can I print a specific memory adress that I passed as a parameter ?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I want to print an adress memory, but I want to pass it as parameter. I tried this, but it wasn't how I wanted.

I did some comparisons between two codes that print memories of vectors, and printed in one case only, the same memory, but the value contained in it, was different in both codes.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i,vet[10];

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        vet[i] = i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf(" %d ", vet[i]);

    printf("\n\n");

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        printf(" %d ", &vet[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

In the code above, I just printed an array, and its memory address.

So, the code below, I printed an array and its memory, but I purposely printed more than my vector allowed.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, vet[2] = {0, 1};  /*I declared just 2 positions of memory*/

    printf("\n %d ", &vet[1]);
    printf("\n %d ", vet[1]);

    for(i=0; i<100; i++)  /*And printed 100 positions, so, printed memory that does not belong to it*/
    {
        printf("\n %d ", &*(vet + i) );
        printf(" %d ", vet[i] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, every time I ran the first code, I obtained a memory that also is printed when I run the second code, but the values inside them are different. Why ?

Comment: You should print addresses with `%p`, not `%d`.

Comment: I just want to show the adress with %d, because i want it in decimal.

Comment: Assuming your C library has a `uintptr_t` type in `<stdint.h>`, you can use `printf("%ju", (uintptr_t)&vet[1]);` for example. However, not every machine has those necessary things, so a bit of checking of integer sizes is needed to find a type that fits if one exists (e.g. `size_t` with `%zu` or `unsigned long long` with `%llu` or `unsigned long` width `%lu`, but they won't necessarily work either). Otherwise, you simply don't have an integer type large enough to hold the value of a pointer, in which case you are stuck with `%p`, which many would say you should be using anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every program runs in its own virtual memory space, so it is highly improbable that your 2nd program can access the memory locations of your first program, hence what you are printing is junk values, stored in that particular logical position inside your second program's memory space.

And even in a program's allocated memory space, same variable might be allotted different memory location on different runs.

EDIT:

You are trying to say that the memory location that gets printed is the same, but the value is different. that is expected, because, the memory location you are printing is the LOGICAL memory location inside the current program, but not the same PHYSICAL memory location and since both the program have same structure, so LOGICAL memory location is same.

Try declaring a new variable before array definition in the second program, you will then get different values for the memory you are printing.

EDIT:

Program 1 , suppose runs in PHYSICAL location

1000 - 2000

it writes the array at 1200-1400

logical location is 200-400

third element is at say 600 logical location  , i.e. 1600 physical location

Program 2 runs in Physical location

3000-4000

starts the array at 3200

now you are trying to read 3600, which you are assuming should be 1600, because the memory address returned by the pointer is same 600, but the physical address is 3600, which is not the same as 1600, so you are reading a value written at 3600 by some other program 3,i.e junk

Comment: I think you mean virtual memory space

Comment: @gaurav5430 Ok, but I think it is not only what is happening, please, run it ! Because, even the virtual memory isn't possible to get the same address.

Comment: @X0R40 you will probably never get the same addresses, because whenever you run the program, a new memory space is created to run it, and so it won't be running in the same memory locations as the older program or even the older version of the same program

Comment: @gaurav5430 I understand, and this is not my problem, my second program is not using the same memory of the first. Never it will happen. But if I run it, and overflow my array memory, I can see the memory of other programs, this is why I am asking...

Comment: yes you can see the memory of other programs, but you can not be sure that this is the physical memory of the first program that you are reading. i ll edit my answer with an example

Comment: You're not seeing memory of other programs, you're just seeing random garbage in this program's own memory, because of the buffer overflow.

Comment: @Barmar you are right, i meant to say, you can see the memory overwritten by some other program at some other time, but it would be junk and unexpected

Comment: @X0R40: On a modern operating system you can never see other program's memory unless you invoke some functions for inter process communication. When you overflow, what you see is random garbage.

Comment: @gaurav5430 I just want to print the PHYSICAL memory..What I am tring to do, is print the values of the memory, but the memory isn't being used in my program, I want to make a "scanner" and read all my memory, not all, but at least, a part of it. If you make an big for loop printing an array memory that hasn't been declared (purposely), you may obtain the values of memory that does not belong your program, but another.

Comment: @X0R40 although it generally won't be allowed, but even then , you can't be sure that it is the memory written by Program 1, did you see my example?

Comment: @X0R40 the memory isn't being used in your program does not mean that the memory you are trying to access does not belong to your program, when you run the program, it would initially be allocated some bytes of memory, some of whose values would be overwritten by your code, and the unused memory will contain junk. you will probably not be allowed to access memory beyond this in modern OS, but even if you would, you can't predict which program;s memory is it

Comment: @everyoneabove And what I'm seeing is just garbage ? and probably from the logical memory ? I'm kinda confused now...

Comment: @X0R40 if you know that, what are you trying to achieve then, as posted in your question?

Comment: because nobody understood what I want to do..when I get an answer to why I post here..

Comment: I am very impressed with the patience and willingness to teach people this site has, here in Brazil nobody is thus. Thanks, I will code other programs and when i get one good enought to show my doubt I will edit my answer. Thanks !

Comment: Unless you're running code within the OS, or you're running without an OS, you generally only have access to virtual memory, not physical memory. When some memory is assigned to your process, the OS is supposed to ensure that it contains no remnants of the previous user; either it should be zeroed or randomized. What you may see, though, is memory used by OS libraries within your process.

Comment: @Barman I see the garbage in memory, and is never zeroed. I am using windows 7, and to compile Cygwin.